# SQL Server syntax for named keys/indices inside table declaration

Tags: sql-server

I am creating a database from scratch, and I want to document the database design in a clear way for review/documentation. Therefore I want to:

- Name my primary key `PK_Foo_Bar` inside the table declaration (unlike how I declared my index)
- Name my foreign key `FK_Foo_Baz` inside the table declaration
- Put the named index `IX_Foo_Baz` inside my table declaration

This is my simplified query:

```
CREATE TABLE FOO  
(
    Bar int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, 
    Baz int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Baz(ID)
); 

CREATE INDEX IX_Foo_Baz ON Foo(Baz);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option would be this syntax (defining constraints directly "inline" with the column definition - not at the end of the table definition):

```
CREATE TABLE FOO 
( 
    Bar int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)
       CONSTRAINT PK_Foo_Bar PRIMARY KEY , 
    Baz int NOT NULL
       CONSTRAINT FK_Foo_Baz FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Baz(ID)
);
```

Comment: Just a small correction: it seems that the part: *** CONSTRAINT PK_Foo_Bar (Bar) PRIMARY KEY *** should actually be ***    CONSTRAINT PK_Foo_Bar PRIMARY KEY *** (which makes sense since the statement is connected to the *** Bar *** declaration without a comma separation

Comment: @DaniëlCamps: yes, you're correct - thanks for pointing out - fixed my post

Answer (score 1):

Indices should be a separate row:

```
CREATE TABLE FOO ( 
    Bar int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1), 
    Baz int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY PK_Foo_Bar (Bar),
    FOREIGN KEY FK_Foo_Baz REFERENCES Baz(ID)
);
```

You can find examples at [MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189039.aspx#Anchor_2)

Comment: Thank you for the clear example. Why should indices be a separate row?

Comment: It's a separate entity, so first you declare a field and afterwards you declare an index. I've added a link to MSDN docs.